# Finding the second of the same two words in a line

Tags: python

I am using line.rfind() to find a certain line in an html page and then I am splitting the line to pull out individual numbers. For example:

```
position1 = line.rfind('Wed')
```

This finds this particular line of html code:

```
 <strong class="temp">79<span>&deg;</span></strong><span class="low"><span>Lo</span> 56<span>&deg;</span></span>
```

First I want to pull out the '79', which is done with the following code:

```
if position1 > 0 :
        self.high0 = lines[line_number + 4].split('<span>')[0].split('">')[-1]
```

This works perfectly. The problem I am encountering is trying to extract the '56' from that line of html code. I can't split it between '< span>' and '< /span> since the first '< span>' it finds in the line is after the '79'. Is there a way to tell the script to look for the second occurrence of '< span>'?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Concerns about parsing HTML with regex aside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I've found that regex tends to be fairly useful for grabbing information from limited, machine-generated HTML.

You can pull out both values with a regex like this:

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'<strong class="temp">(\d+).*?<span>Lo</span> (\d+)', lines[line_number+4])
if matches:
    high, low = matches[0]
```

Consider this quick-and-dirty: if you rely on it for a job, you may want to use a real parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. This is just for my own purposes, nothing important. Though I may check out BeautifulSoup anyway. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

html = """
 <strong class="temp">79<span>&deg;</span></strong><span class="low"><span>Lo</span> 56<span>&deg;</span></span>
"""

numbers = re.findall(r"\d+", html, re.X|re.M|re.S)
print numbers

--output:--
['79', '56']
```

With BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<strong class="temp">
    79
    <span>&deg;</span>
</strong>
<span class="low">
   <span>Lo</span> 
   56
   <span>&deg;</span>
</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
low_span = soup.find('span', class_="low")

for string in low_span.stripped_strings:
    print string

--output:--
Lo
56
°
```

Comment: Thanks 7stud. This will be helpful if I decide to use BeautifulSoup.